# Connect to remote MongoDB from Serverless/Lambda

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Using Serverless/Lambda and Node, I am failing to connect to a remote MongoDB database. The database is hosted on a separate EC2 server.

**Here's my Serverless function code:**

```
module.exports.migrateMongoToCompose = async (event, context) => {
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const assert = require('assert');

    console.log(1)

    const mongoUrl = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ec2-13-52-114-61.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/<dbname>";

    // Connect to source DB
    MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, client) {
        console.log(2, err, client)

        assert.equal(null, err);

        console.log("Connected successfully to mongodb", mongoUrl, <dbname>);

        const db = client.db('<dbname>');

        client.close();
    });

};
```

**Here's part of Serverless' config file:**

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  memorySize: 1024
  region: us-west-1
```

I've had a surprising amount of trouble with this. Tried every combination I can think of for the mongo URI, tried using `useNewUrlParser`, tried connecting to a different remote database hosted on Compose.com. Everything I've done has resulting in errors.

When I second-guess my EC2/MongoDB server permissions, I remember that I have no problem connecting via command line on my Mac using this command:

```
mongo --host mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:27017/<dbname>
```

I think you have everything you'd need to repro. Any thoughts? Any clue might help.

Comment: Please check your bindip settings in mongod.conf file for the allowed IP address range. Also, check aws ec2 inbound rule for the allowed IP address range

Comment: Hmm, I think the fact that I can (and you also could) access the instance via command line rules that out. To be thorough, bind_ip is set to 0.0.0.0 and the security group for the ec2 instance is wide open open on port 27017 (inbound).

Comment: Make sure you didn't put your lambda into VPC and its security group simply doesn't allow the necessary outbound traffic. You could globally do that in serverless.yml under the 'provider' key

Comment: Welp, I don’t think it’s in a VPC. The drop down on the function page says “No VPC”. Just to test, I successfully retrieved a response from a GET request to Wikipedia. :/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for this problem. Let me list down some of them

1. check the security group of the EC2 is it has correct inbound permissions.
2. the pass in the connection string must be URL encoded.
3. Check if you've allowed all the correct IP or given public access from the mongodb.

If these do not work please send the error logs here